# Null Reference Exception in Recursive Function

Tags: f#

The code below is from chapter 8 of https://www.manning.com/books/real-world-functional-programming

When I run the code I receive a Null Reference Exception in testClientTree. I checked the errata for the book but did not find anything for this.

```
type Client =
  { Name : string
    Income : int
    YearsInJob : int
    UsesCreditCard : bool
    CriminalRecord : bool }

let john = 
  { Name = "John Doe"  
    Income = 40000
    YearsInJob = 1
    UsesCreditCard = true
    CriminalRecord = false }

type ClientTests = 
  { Check   : Client -> bool
    Report : Client -> unit }

type QueryInfo =
  { Title : string
    Test : Client -> bool
    Positive : Decision
    Negative : Decision }
    
and Decision = 
  | Result of string  
  | Query of QueryInfo

let rec tree = 
    Query({ Title = "More than $40k" 
            Test = (fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000)
            Positive = moreThan40; Negative = lessThan40 })
and moreThan40 = 
    Query({ Title = "Has criminal record"
            Test = (fun cl -> cl.CriminalRecord)
            Positive = Result("NO"); Negative = Result("YES") })
and lessThan40 = 
    Query({ Title = "Years in job"
            Test = (fun cl -> cl.YearsInJob > 1)
            Positive = Result("YES"); Negative = usesCredit })
and usesCredit = 
    Query({ Title = "Uses credit card"
            Test = (fun cl -> cl.UsesCreditCard)
            Positive = Result("YES"); Negative = Result("NO") })

let rec testClientTree(client, tree) =
  match tree with
  | Result(msg) ->
      printfn "  OFFER A LOAN: %s" msg
  | Query(qi) ->
      let s, case = if (qi.Test(client)) then "yes", qi.Positive
                    else "no", qi.Negative
      printfn "  - %s? %s" qi.Title s
      testClientTree(client, case)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    testClientTree(john, tree)
    0
```

Comment: You can fix it by simply removing the `rec` and `and` from the `tree` and the following three definitions - make them simply `let` - and reorder the four to make it all compile.

Comment: There's an awful lot of extra parentheses that aren't needed, and make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why the book has this initialization code, but the reason why it fails is because data is actually not initialized.

You'll need to do it like this:

```
let rec tree = 
    Query({ Title = "More than $40k" 
            Test = (fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000)
            Positive = 
                Query({ Title = "Has criminal record"
                        Test = (fun cl -> cl.CriminalRecord)
                        Positive = Result("NO")
                        Negative = Result("YES") })
            Negative = 
                Query({ Title = "Years in job"
                        Test = (fun cl -> cl.YearsInJob > 1)
                        Positive = Result("YES");
                        Negative = 
                            Query({ Title = "Uses credit card"
                                    Test = (fun cl -> cl.UsesCreditCard)
                                    Positive = Result("YES"); Negative = Result("NO") })})})
```

It's for reasons like this that it's probably better not to define a bunch of mutually recursive stuff if you can.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is a F# compiler bug [Initialization of mutually recursive values can sometimes leave fields uninitialized #6750](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/6750)

What you can do with this?

1. Do not use mutually recursive values. Use `let` binding and reorder things as Bent suggested (I would go this way)
2. Do not use mutually recursive values. Use one big initialization as Phillip suggested
3. Delay definition with `lazy` expression
4. Use a function expression that references values that are defined recursively

Before we jump to examples, I suggest changing the definition of Decision to make results explicit and get rid of strings:

```
Decision = 
  | Approved
  | Declined
  | Query of QueryInfo
```

Also, I would recommend naming queries according to what they query instead of the part previous query which resulted in a new query. I.e. instead of `lessThan40` use `checkYearsInJob`.

So, the simplest way - reordered `let` bindings

```
let checkCriminalRecord =
    Query { Title = "Has criminal record"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.CriminalRecord
            Positive = Declined
            Negative = Approved }
let checkCreditCardUsage =
    Query { Title = "Uses credit card"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.UsesCreditCard
            Positive = Approved
            Negative = Declined }
let checkYearsInJob =
    Query { Title = "Years in job"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.YearsInJob > 1
            Positive = Approved
            Negative = checkCreditCardUsage }
let checkIncome =
    Query { Title = "More than $40k"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000
            Positive = checkCriminalRecord
            Negative = checkYearsInJob }
```

---

Delaying with `lazy` (note that both Positive and Negative fields should be declared as `Lazy<Decision>`)

```
let rec checkIncome =
    Query { Title = "More than $40k"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000
            Positive = lazy checkCriminalRecord
            Negative = lazy checkYearsInJob }
and checkCriminalRecord =
    Query { Title = "Has criminal record"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.CriminalRecord
            Positive = lazy Declined
            Negative = lazy Approved }
and checkYearsInJob =
    Query { Title = "Years in job"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.YearsInJob > 1
            Positive = lazy Approved
            Negative = lazy checkCreditCardUsage }
and checkCreditCardUsage =
    Query { Title = "Uses credit card"
            Test = fun cl -> cl.UsesCreditCard
            Positive = lazy Approved
            Negative = lazy Declined }
```

When testing tree force a case to execute a value

```
testClientTree(client, case.Force())
```

---

And last, using functions. Here I would change the query definition to return decision directly from test:

```
type QueryInfo =
  { Title : string
    Test : Client -> Decision }
```

You still can return a boolean result of the test, but focusing on the loan offer makes code cleaner:

```
let rec checkIncome =
    Query { Title = "More than $40k"
            Test = fun c -> if c.Income > 40000 then checkCriminal else checkYearsInJob }
and checkCriminal =
    Query { Title = "Has criminal record"
            Test = fun c -> if c.CriminalRecord then Declined else Approved }
and checkYearsInJob =
    Query { Title = "Years in job"
            Test = fun c -> if c.YearsInJob > 1 then Approved else checkCreditCardUsage }
and checkCreditCardUsage =
    Query { Title = "Uses credit card"
            Test = fun c -> if c.UsesCreditCard then Approved else Declined }
```